# How to get business hours from google maps api?

Tags: google-maps

I am looking to consume google maps api which can return me business hours if I provide exact name and address of the business. I tried searching for this on Google but could not find any good references. Can someone point me in right direction ? Which API I should be looking at ? What kind of response value I should expect to get from google.

Thanks
Ved

Comment: There currently isn't any API or service providing this information.